# Exporting html output to latex, .png or .doc

Tags: r, export, crosstab

I am doin some cross tabulation with the `sjPlot` package that produces wonderful tables in HTML.

```
library(sjPlot)
iris<-iris
tab_xtab(iris$Species,iris$Sepal.Width,show.row.prc = TRUE,show.col.prc = TRUE)
```

While the output looks great in the consol, I would like to export it and put them in a report. Ideally, I would like to export them into a latex file, but also as a .png as a .doc file would be ok.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

thanks a lot for your help

Best

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63053465/how-to-convert-an-html-sjtable-from-the-sjplot-package-to-latex?rq=1) works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `webshot::webshot()`:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(webshot)

# location to write html version to
my_html <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")

# write html to temp file
tab_xtab(iris$Species,
         iris$Sepal.Width,
         show.row.prc = TRUE,
         show.col.prc = TRUE, 
         file = my_html)

# location to write png version to
my_png <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")

# take a webshot of html and save to png
webshot::webshot(my_html, my_png, vheight = 300)
```

[image]

Note, you will likely have to install PhantomJS after installing the `webshot` package. This can be done with `webshot::install_phantomjs()`.

You may also have to play around with the `vwidth` and `vheight` arguments to avoid extra white-space in your png.